# Finding the Balance in a Math Question (Teaching)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education

As we try to work and teach in the midst of this pandemic, some problems arise when making online math exams. My questions is simple: What could be an interesting basic differentiation question such that students doing the online exam still have to work a bit to get it, rather than simply Googling it or using WolframAlpha/Mathematica to solve it for them?

Everything I can think of seems to be either too easy (meaning they can easily solve it online) or too demanding. I'm struggling to find a good balance, if there is any. This is a first-year math module I'm teaching (non-math students).

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps better asked at math educators stack exchange. One idea: consider presenting sketches of graphs and asking for sketches of the derivative, or asking questions about the derivative. No algebra required. Or asking whether/why the height of water in a pictured tank is rising slower and slower as water enters at a constant rate.

Comment: i'm having a hard time with this (probably along with everyone). ideally, i try to write questions that are harder to cheat on, but not harder to solve. this only works sometimes, and it often ends up being a choice between "do i write hard questions" or "do i have inflated grades."

Comment: I also have found that things I consider slight deviations can REALLY throw students off in lower level math classes. I'll ask, for example, for the derivative of $kx^2$ instead of $3x^2$, and far more people cannot answer. (I found this to be the case in person too, so its not just a cheating phenomenon.)

Comment: Any word problem is good at preventing cheating. Another technique that I can think of is to ask for indirect result so there is an additional step after finding unknown variable to get the final answer.

Comment: An idea:  give a multiple choice exam, and limit the time.  After the exam, insert some of your original questions into Google, and see what comes up!  Search again a couple of weeks after the exam $\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

How about proving a more obscure result from first principles?

For example:

> Prove using first principles that
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(x\sin x)=\sin x +x\cos x$$
> You may assume that $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}=0,~~\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}{h}=1.$

As a high school student myself I'd say that is potentially the most challenging part of differentiation (at least at high school level).

However, I think it also depends on what stage your students are at. Have they learnt the chain rule, product rule, quotient rule? Can they differentiate any logarithm? Can they differentiate any exponential and basic trigonometric functions? Can they differentiate inverse trigonometric and hyperbolic functions? Can they derive Maclaurin series for a given function? Can they use l'Hopital's rule?

Additionally, do you want them to use other skills in this question as well, such as knowledge of trigonometric identities?

---

Alternatively, perhaps you could ask them to prove certain results using differentiation. For example, if they are proficient in sigma notation and algebra:

> Given the standard formula for the value of a geometric series, use differentiation to prove that
> $$\sum_{r=1}^n ra^r=\frac{a(na^{n+1}-(n+1)a^n+1)}{(a-1)^2}$$
> Hence evaluate
> $$\sum_{r=1}^{13} r2^r$$

This may be too challenging, but it will hopefully be interesting and stimulating for your students.

Another example may be:

> Use differentiation to prove that
> $$\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\equiv\tan\frac{x}{2}+A$$
> for some constant $A$. Now find the value of $A$.

Comment: What a curious exercise. Thank you so much for the suggestion! They can do all that apart from Maclaurin series.

Comment: @samwolfe you're welcome, I'm very glad to have helped you! I will try to think up some more interesting questions that you may want to use. What about the final q in my post about whether you'd like to test their knowledge on trig identities?

Comment: @samwolfe please see another 2 suggestions I have added.